# (Android) IntentService Kill its process

Tags: android, process, intentservice

Something strange happens to me. I use IntentService but when its done it closes the process that contains it. this is the main (and only one) process of my app so it closes all the app... I solved this by isolating it in another process using `android:process=".BackgroundIntentService"` (I run this intentService from a background service)

Is it suppose to be like this? How can it effect my app?

Comment: Donot use IntentService if your need is to run continuously into background. IntentService stops after onHandleIntent finishes, Use service instead.

Comment: service  may also close when memory is less

Comment: I use IntentService cause I need to do a short action in separate thread.